# A word like "footing" for healthy activity on foot

Tags: word-request, nouns

In Italian, we use a word that should be a loanword to mean "an activity such as race or march, practiced for training or healthy activity": *footing*.

An American friend of mine has never understood what I mean, and told me she doesn't use *footing* like that. I also looked at the NOAD, and the OED; both report the meaning of *footing*, but they don't give to the word the meaning we give in Italian.

What is the word that I should use to describe that kind of activity?

Comment: *Racing* and *marching* imply that you're doing it with other people. Is that the case? Or can you go footing by yourself?

Comment: It seems I missed the comment. Yes, I am referring to an activity generally done alone; you could go _footing_ with somebody else, but it is not required as it is with _racing_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean particularly foot based activities, i.e. *running*, *heavy walking*? Because, if it is so, then perhaps you can use *jogging*, which is like a light and gentle run.

Answer (score 2):

As Barrie says, the most common "generic" term is simply *exercise*, but there are alternatives:

The majority of 10,000 written instances of [*I **work out** to*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20work%20out%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are followed by things like *"stay healthy"*, but that expression doesn't tend to include outdoor activities like *jogging, cycling*, or "competitive games" such as *squash* which are often engaged in mainly for the health benefits.

It's also common in the UK to hear, for example, *"I go [**[circuit] training**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_training) to keep in shape"*, but I don't know if that usage is common in the US. And, again, it doesn't cover other activities as given above.

Answer (score 1):

I think most native speakers of English would just call it *exercise*, even though the word can mean other kinds of activity as well.